# Python help: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am learning Python, getting this error in my code. Searched online, but didn't find an answer I understand. Can someone help?

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Here is my code:

```
while True:
    print("Enter 'add' to add two numbers")
    print("Enter 'quit' to quit the program")
    user_input = input(": ")

    if user_input == "quit":
        break
    elif user_input == "add":
        num1 = float(input("Enter 1st number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter 2nd number: "))
        result = str(num1 + num2)
        print("Answer is: " + result)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce in Python 3. Can you show the full error?

Comment: it's not problem , it's worked for me ,  do you use python 3 ?

Comment: you probably redefined `str` to something else

Comment: Or `input`, or `float`.

Comment: @CristiFati yes. But `str` is the "ideal" variable to assign to a string :) seems that I "guessed" right. With a traceback that would've been clearer, now I realize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's what happens when you're using built-in functions to define your variables:

```
>>> str = "string"
>>> str(12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

this kind of `str` assignment must have been performed before this code, which is okay. Quickfix:

```
del str
```

Proper fix: find where this variable is defined and rename / delete it.

(note that `input` or `float` could be the names that have been redefined)